# Scheme Guile: apply function all ellements but last one

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, fold, guile

I need to apply a function to all elements but the last one in a list. Basically I am writing a kind of toy compiler, so given a arithmetic term like this:

```
   (+ 1 10)
```

I would like to get something like

```
  Plus(1, 10)
```

I managed to get the following:

```
  Plus(1, 10 ,)
```

By using the map function:

```
(string-append "Plus ("   
                         (fold-right string-append ""  
                             (map (lambda (x) (string-append x ",")) (map compile-term (cdr t)))))
```

where compile-term is the function I am writing and t is the term I compile.

So my question is the following, is there a clean way to apply a function to all elements but the last one of a list using Guile Scheme? Or the only solution it would be to use loops as indicated [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/while-do.html).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try string-join to put commas between terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use  [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output.html) for this kind of cases. The following tested* code (thanks @Chris Jester-Young)  might do what you need:

```
(format #f "~a(~{~a~^, ~})" (compile-term (car seq))
                            (map compile-term (cdr seq)))
```

When you have a state, you might prefer to use `fold-*`. Your `string-append` could be replaced by an anonymous function that calls `string-append` on the compile terms, and skip the comma when called with the initial value of `fold`.

Comment: Very nice! You're quite a `format` wizard. :-) (Yes, I did test this for you.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Well, this is useful for golfing ;-)